# input numbers in textfield with RTL direction shows wrong output

Tags: html, css, forms, bidi

I'm trying to support RTL direction (for Arabic language) in my web-app. There's a weird thing happening with my textfields. When I input AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD, i'm getting the correct display in the text field but when I try to input numbers, I'm getting a weird output. let's say my html code only contains

```
<input type="text" size="30"/>
```

and my css contains

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Try to input

AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
- notice that the output is correct.

Try to input

1111 2222 3333 4444
- notice what happens in the textfield.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Note: I can't use javascript in this because this is for mobile browsers. Particularly low-end devices.

Comment: You should explain what happens, instead of calling it “weird” and telling others to “notice what happens”.

Comment: Isn't this how Arabic is supposed to behave?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yeah that's I provided the code and tried my best to give you an overview on how to test this problem.

Comment: @Jack i'm not sure about that

Comment: I've confirmed this with someone that has some knowledge about the subject :)

Comment: The I guess there's no fix for this :D I just need to prove this to my PM. :D

Comment: Fix to which problem exactly? If your purpose is to make the textfield writing direction RTL, then you seem to be getting just that.

Comment: If you just want right alignment without the rules that come with RTL you simply use `text-align: right` :)

Answer (score 2):

use this class:

```
.number_ltr {
    direction: ltr!important;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
}
```

so your HTML code should looks like:

```
<input class="number_ltr" type="text" size="30"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though Arabic is written from right to left, individual groups of numbers (e.g. "123") are written as is. For example:

```
<-- reading direction
456 123
```

Gets interpreted as "123 followed by 456".

Also, from what I can tell, the use of letters A-Z affects how grouped numbers are written; digit groups that follow such alphabets are written from left to right, e.g. "abc 123 456" comes out as expected.

Comment: The text of the first sentence does not match the example. Groups of digits are written according to the overall writing direction (right to left for Arabic), though within such a group, digits go left to right.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The first part of the example is how you type it, the second part is how it appears basically ... let me see if I can clear that up a bit more.

Comment: “Typing direction” is misleading expression here, and the text should really start with something like “The writing direction right-to-left affects groups of digits, too.” This is *not* a deviation from the general rule that Arabic is written right to left but an implication of it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've revised the answer. Hope it's more accurate now.

Answer (score 0):

The “weird” thing seems to be that the input 1111 2222 3333 4444 appears so that 1111 is rightmost, 2222 is the left of it, etc. This is *correct* behavior for `direction: rtl`. Digits have weak neutrality, and in the absence of characters with strong directionality, the strings of digits run according to the directionality set (here `rtl`). The [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) specifies this. Notice how things change if you enter first a Latin letter, then the digits.

If the page is supposed to have right to left directionality, then the rules of such directionality should normally be applied in text input fields, too. If you wish to have text field with left to right directionality, for some reason, then set the HTML attribute `dir=ltr` on it. (It is generally better to use HTML rather than CSS for directionality, since directionality is not just an optional presentational suggestion but part of the rules of a writing system.)